# OpenCV2 createBackgroundSubtractorMOG Attribute not found

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, background-subtraction

I am using cv2 version 4.0.0 and python version 3.7.2.

I am trying to subtract Background using this method `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` and its working well.

But when I use `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()` its not working its showing me

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute
>   'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG '.

I also tried `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()` but i got same error

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute
>   'BackgroundSubtractorMOG'.

and another subtraction method `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG()` also not working.

I also refer other stackoverflow answers but I didn't get solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MOG2 containts in main opencv repository. MOG and GMG are from opencv_contrib: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/bgsegm

Comment: its working after installing opencv-contrib. thank you @Nuzhny.

Answer (score 4):

there are two subtraction packages in opencv. BackgroundSubtractorMOG() it's at `cv2.bgsegm.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()`,to use you must install opencv-contrib-python